# trouble with partial template specialisations

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-specialization, partial-specialization

I have the following class structure

```
// file foo.h:

struct foo_base
{ ... }

template<typename T> struct foo : foo_base
{ ... };

template<typename F>
using is_foo = std::is_convertible<F,foo_base>;

template<typename, typename=void> struct aux;

template<typename Foo>
struct aux<Foo, typename std::enable_if<is_foo<Foo>::value>::type>
{ ... };           // specialisation for any foo
```

```
// file bar.h:
#include "foo.h"

template<typename T> struct bar : foo<T>
{ ... };

template<typename T>
struct aux<bar<T>>
{ ... };           // specialisation for bar<T>
```

Now, the problem is that for `aux<bar<T>>` both specialisations provided for `aux` are viable. Is there a way to avoid this disambiguity without providing another specialisation for every `T`? Note that modifications to file `foo.h` must not know about file `bar.h`.

*Note* The ambiguity shall be resolved such that the specialisation provided in file `bar.h` is picked for any `aux<bar<T>>`. Originally, `bar` was not a template and the specialisation `aux<bar>` not partial and hence preferred. The problem arose by making `bar` a template.

Comment: How is `is_foo` defined? Can provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: How do you want the ambiguity to be resolved?

Comment: @Praetorian see edits. `is_foo<bar<T>>::value` is `true` (otherwise there was no ambiguity)

Comment: @Walter It would be nice to see a real application, as there are too much ways to fix this.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph `std::enable_if<is_foo<Foo>::value>::type`, here `type` is a dependent name in `std::enable_if<...>` which means that *typename* **is** required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler doesn't see `struct aux<bar<T>>` as more specialised than `struct aux<Foo, typename std::enable_if<is_foo<Foo>::value>::type>` because of second template argument. You can specify the second argument the same way in your `bar<T>` specialisation:

```
template<typename T>
struct aux<bar<T>, typename std::enable_if<is_foo<bar<T>>::value>::type>
{ };
```

The rules for how specialised partial template specialisations are are complicated, but I will try to explain very briefly:

The three (your two, plus my one) relevant specialisations are

```
template<typename Foo>
struct aux<Foo, typename std::enable_if<is_foo<Foo>::value>::type>

template<typename T>
struct aux<bar<T>> // or aux<bar<T>, void>
{ };

template<typename T>
struct aux<bar<T>, typename std::enable_if<is_foo<bar<T>>::value>::type>
{ };
```

Per the standard (14.5.5.2), to determine which of the class template partial specialisations is the most specialised, the question that needs to be answered is which of the following function template overloads would be the best match in a call to `f(aux<bar<T>>())`:

```
template<typename Foo>
void f(aux<Foo, typename std::enable_if<is_foo<Foo>::value>::type>); // 1

template<typename T>
void f(aux<bar<T>>); // or aux<bar<T>, void> // 2

template<typename T>
void f(aux<bar<T>, typename std::enable_if<is_foo<bar<T>>::value>::type>); // 3
```

And there, in turn, the partial ordering rules for functions say that 1 is not more specialised than 2, and that 2 is not more specialised than 1, roughly speaking, because 1 is not *clearly* more specialised than 2, and 2 is not *clearly* more specialised than 1. "Clearly more specialised" is not how the standard words it, but that essentially means that based on the type arguments of one of those, the type arguments of the other are not deducible.

When comparing 1 and 3, however, the arguments of 1 are deducible from 3: `Foo` can be deduced as `bar<T>`. Therefore, 3 is at least as specialised as 1. However, the arguments of 3 are not deducible from 1: `T` cannot be deduced at all. The compiler's conclusion therefore is that 3 is more specialised than 1.

Comment: Wow. That seems to work. But I don't quite understand how/why. If I simply specialise as `struct aux<bar<T>, void>` it doesn't work. Perhaps you can give some more explanation/insight.

Comment: @Walter I've attempted to explain, but it's a very complicated subject, and I may have made some mistakes. Please take a look and see if it helps.

Comment: @hvd +1 but see my solution for a way to also allow further derived classes to match the pattern.

Answer (score 2):

**Partial specialization** of **class templates** is based on **pattern matching**. In contrast, customizing **function templates** is based on **template argument deduction** and **overload resolution**.

Because of the **class hierarchy** present in your problem, customizing behavior would in principle be more convenient through function template overloading, because that can take **derived-to-base conversions** into account. The pattern matching used in partial class template specialization does not provide the same flexibility.

However, since C++11, it is possible to do compile-time return type deduction. Here is a solution that combines **tag dispatching, default constructors and `decltype` type deduction**:

```
#include <iostream>

// file foo_base.h:

struct foo_base 
{ 
    foo_base() = default; 
};

foo_base faux(foo_base const&)
{ 
    return foo_base{}; 
}

template<class T, class = decltype(faux(T{}))>
struct aux;

template<class T>
struct aux<T, foo_base> 
{ 
    enum { value = 1 }; 
};

// file foo.h:

template<typename T> 
struct foo : foo_base  
{ 
    foo() = default; 
};

// file bar.h:

template<typename T> 
struct bar : foo<T> 
{ 
    bar() = default; 
};

template<class T>
bar<T> faux(bar<T> const&) 
{ 
    return bar<T>{}; 
}

template<class T, class U>
struct aux<T, bar<U>> 
{ 
    enum { value = 2 }; 
};

// file meow.h

template<class T>
struct meow : bar<T>
{
    meow() = default;    
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << aux<foo_base>::value;  // 1
    std::cout << aux<foo<int>>::value;  // 1
    std::cout << aux<bar<int>>::value;  // 2
    std::cout << aux<meow<int>>::value; // 2
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/796b4090353ca949) that works with both g++ and clang in C++11 mode (C++14 mode is not required!).

The `constexpr` function `faux()` is overloaded for `foo_bar` and as a function template for `bar<T>`. Any argument whose class is derived from `foo_base` but not from `bar<T>` will select the former overload, and anything derived from `bar<T>` will select the latter overload. This mechanism is the same as e.g. in the Standard Library where iterator categories are used to **tag dispatch** several implementations of `std::advance()` e.g.

To use this selection mechanism during partial specialization of your class template `aux`, two more ingredients are required. First, all classes are required to have a **default constructor**. Secondly, **`decltype()`** is applied to that expression `faux(T{})` to **deduce the return type**.

> **NOTE**: it is not required that `faux()` is `constexpr` or that any of the default constructors are `constexpr`, because `decltype()` will
>   not actually evaluate the function call but only deduce its return
>   type.

The main class template `aux` has a default template argument:

```
template<class T, class = decltype(faux(T{}))>
struct aux;
```

Partially specializing the second argument on `foo_base` allows you to provide behavior for any class that derives from `foo_base`:

```
template<class T>
struct aux<T, foo_base> 
{ // custom behavior for anything derived from foo_bar };
```

The second partial specialization matches any class derived from any template instantiation `bar<U>`

```
template<class T, class U>
struct aux<T, bar<U>> 
{ // custom behavior for anything derived from bar<U> for some U }
```

**NOTE**: the main drawback is that you might need to provide a default constructor to all classes in your hierarchy. This may or may not be an obstacle that you can overcome. Most classes already have a default constructor, but some may not. In that sense this solution is intrusive (i.e. it cannot be bolted on top of existing code, but it requires modification of that code).

Comment: Clever answer. It assumes that classes derived from `bar` should be matched, even though the OP's code wouldn't match them, but that may well be a correct assumption.

Comment: @hvd I just discovered that `constexpr` is not even required, because `decltype` doesn't actually evaluate the function call, it just deduces the return type!

Comment: @hvd it's quite easy to only match `bar<T>`, just provide a `aux<bar<T>>` partial specialization.

Comment: Sure, but if you only need to match `bar<T>`, your answer is more complicated than mine for no benefit. The benefit of your answer lies in its flexibility that allows it to match derived classes too. :)

Comment: @hvd yes, I like your solution as well. I was mainly looking to map a set of function overloads to a set of class specializations. The other way around is idiomatic of course because it's a 1-to-many mapping through `template<class T> auto fun(T const& t) { return helper_class<T>()(t); }`. Here it's a faithfull many-to-many mapping.

Comment: @hvd IOW, the real benefit to me is that the entire *class hierarchy* is reflected in the set of partial specializations, just as it would be with the usual tag dispatching for function templates

Comment: I think that's what I was saying (or at least trying to say) too, but I get confused easily. I think we're in agreement, anyway, and I do think your answer is more powerful and useful in general than mine.